# adding native iphone camera zoom slider and youtube player controller to my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, camera

Sorry for squeezing two questions into one, just figured those may be related and with respect to the DB storage at SO...

I am trying to find out a way to add the iphone camera native zoom slider as well as something similar to the youtube app player controller. I am guessing that the youtube one may be a custom button or something, but did not find a way to add the zoom slider.

I would like to add those two as overlay to a camera view that I am using within the app.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `UIKit` artwork with https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor.
For the movie player controls you could use three `UIButton` and one `UISlider`.
For the camera control you could subclass `UIControl` or `UISlider`.